# Using linq to join/union two objects with different columns

Tags: c#, linq

I have to two objects, one created from a csv (`fileAuto,first`) and the other from a datatable(`dbAuto,second`). Both have `count` column.

I want to join the two on multiple columns and the result, to contain items from the second that do not match the first, and also to contain the `count` column and from the first and add it to a list.

I thought I wanted to use `.Except()`, but I didn't know how to have the have a comparer to compare multiple columns. I thought a join would work but I'm getting an error saying *one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect*.

I have a loose understanding of Linq, so I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. I've included my code for the latter.

```
public class FileAuto
{
    public string DealerCode;        
    public string ModelCode;
    public int ModelYear;
    public string ExteriorCodeCode;
    public string InteriorColorCode;
    public int FileVehicleCount;
}

public class DbAuto
{
    public string DealerCode;
    public string DealershipName;
    public string ModelCode;
    public int ModelYear;
    public string ExteriorCodeCode;
    public string InteriorColorCode;
    public int DbVehicleCount;
}

public class IDiscObj // INVENTORY DISCREPANCIES object
{
    public string DealerCode;
    public string DealershipName;
    public string ModelCode;
    public int ModelYear;
    public string ExteriorCodeCode;
    public string InteriorColorCode;
    public int FileVehicleCount;
    public int DbVehicleCount;
}

var autoscombined = 
    from f in fileInv
    join d in dbInv
        on 
            new {f.DealerCode, f.ModelCode, f.ModelYear, f.ExteriorCodeCode, f.InteriorColorCode} 
        equals 
            new {d.DealerCode, d.ModelCode, d.ModelYear, d.ExteriorCodeCode, d.InteriorColorCode}
    select (a => new IDiscObj {
        DealerCode = f.DealerCode,
        DealershipName = d.DealershipName,
        ModelCode = f.ModelCode,
        ModelYear = f.ModelYear,
        ExteriorCodeCode = f.ExteriorCodeCode,
        InteriorColorCode = f.InteriorColorCode,
        FileVehicleCount = f.FileVehicleCount,
        DbVehicleCount = d.DbVehicleCount
        });
```

I also hope to take these results and sum both vehicle counts grouped by dealercode which I have listed below. If someone could tell me if I'm on the right track for either of these solutions or a more appropriate way of accomplishing this would be great.

```
if (DDOlst.Count > 0) //list of IDiscObj 
{
    var ddos = 
        from d in DDOlst
        group d by new { d.DealerCode, d.DealershipName } into g
        select 
            new { 
                g.Key.DealerCode, 
                g.Key.DealershipName, 
                filecnt = g.Sum(d => d.FileVehicleCount), 
                dbcnt = g.Sum(d => d.DbVehicleCount) 
                };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need `a=>` in your select clause:

```
var autoscombined = from f in fileInv
    join d in dbInv
    on new {f.DealerCode, f.ModelCode, f.ModelYear, f.ExteriorCodeCode, f.InteriorColorCode} 
        equals new {d.DealerCode, d.ModelCode, d.ModelYear, d.ExteriorCodeCode, d.InteriorColorCode}
    select new IDiscObj {
        DealerCode = f.DealerCode,
        DealershipName = d.DealershipName,
        ModelCode = f.ModelCode,
        ModelYear = f.ModelYear,
        ExteriorCodeCode = f.ExteriorCodeCode,
        InteriorColorCode = f.InteriorColorCode,
        FileVehicleCount = f.FileVehicleCount,
        DbVehicleCount = d.DbVehicleCount
    };
```